# redirect to root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

My route has *root* set to :

```
root :to => "posts#index", :locale => :en
```

But /en/posts/ and /en/posts/index is still accessible, showing "duplicate" content from the root_path. I would like to redirect to root_path, if one of those paths is used.

That way, I can avoid duplicate content in search engines and my users have a more consistent experience: a resource lives on only one place and one place only (REST).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now.  Did you ever figure out the answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off the posts/index url by editing the posts resource in your routes.rb file to look like this:

```
resources :posts, :except => :index
```

If this gives you issues with redirection, read the rails guides on routing, specifically section [3.12 Redirection](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

Comment: Yea, but if I disable posts#index, that page no longer works. I still want the posts#index as page: as the root. I just want it available under only one of the urls /, /posts or /posts/index, not all three.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a solution to this issue by using the following in my routes.rb:

```
get "/en/posts" => redirect("/")
resources :posts
root :to => "posts#index", :locale => :en
```

Requests to /en/posts gets 301 redirected (Moved permanently) to the root path